# Passing a model object (with many fields) from a viewfunction to another using redirect and without saving it

Tags: python, django, redirect, view, model

I am quite new in this field... so be gentle :)
The problem can be stated as follow:
View 1: a form based on a model of 14 fields is presented. The user fills it and presses the post button. (important: not saving the model instance in the DB)
View 2: A confirmation page appears containing a summary of what he entered. He is asked then to 
- cancel (don't bother to erase anything in the database)
- edit (is not yet saved but the information can be changed)
- confirm it (now it's time to save it in the database).

And should be accessible only one time, if not completed... it disappears (avoid to create an enormous number of instance in the DB)

At the moment everything is static as it save in the DB from the start and stay there, so if someone jsut leave, it will remain in the DB for nothing

I looked for some solutions but always cracked below errors.
The first one is to directly pass the model instance (Mycard) which landed to > 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' 
So I looked to pass the information through the URL but it looks like it will be extremely long afterward... 
I tried as well with request.session but it says that my model is not a compatible JSON file > Object of type 'MyCardProfile' is not JSON serializable.

I am using Django 2.1.7

models.py

```py
class MyCardProfile(models.Model):
    """ This model defines the fields required for a my card """

    # identity of the post user
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    # The Card information:
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)    


    # Short title description
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, default='Check it') 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)

    # Managing
    manager1 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100) 
    manager2 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100) 

    # Tracking
    status = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    end_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
        Form for the Card
    """
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Name',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'name'}))
    title = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Short title', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe it in short','id':'title'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email'}))

    place = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Place', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'place'}))

    description = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Description', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Tell us something.'}))


    class Meta:
        model = MkProfile
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'place', 'title', 'description', ]
```

views.py

```py
def formMy(request):
    context = {}
    context['pagename'] = "My form"

    if request.method == 'POST':

        My_card = MyForm(request.POST)

        if My_card.is_valid():
            Mycard = My_card.save(commit=False)          
            Mycard.manager = 'example1'
            Mycard.manager2 = 'example2'
            Mycard.save() #I would like to avoid that

            return redirect('formMyconfirmation', id=Mycard.pk)

    else:
        My_card = MyForm()
        pictures_form = MyPicturesForm()

    context['Myform'] = My_card    
    return render(request, 'forms/formMy.html', context)




def formMyconfirmation(request, id):

    ##I would like to have access to the unsaved Mycard##
    context = {}
    context['pagename'] = 'My Card #'+str(id)+' confirmation'
    Mycard = get_object_or_404(MyCardProfile, id=id)
    context['meldekarte'] = Mycard

    if request.method == 'POST':
    ##It's here that I would like to save Mycard##
        return redirect('survey', id=Mycard.pk)

    return render(request, "forms/formMyconfirmation.html", context)
```

url.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('My/', user_views.formMy, name='formMy'),
    path('My_confirm/<int:id>/', user_views.formMy_confirmation, name='formMyconfirmation'),
    path('My_edit/<int:id>/', user_views.formMy_edit, name='formMyedit'),
    path('My_delete/<int:id>/', user_views.formMy_delete, name='formMydelete'),
    path('survey/<int:id>/', user_views.survey, name='survey'),
]
```

My wish is to not save the data in the View1 (formMy), but pass the information directly to the View2 (formMy_confirmation) and then save it when its confirmed... This way nobody can access the confirmation afterwards (maybe there is another way to do it) or fill the db with useless information if it's not completed.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: take a look at django-formtools (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hey, thank you... I check that directly

Comment: @HenryM Thank you a lot, I started and apparently it works for the preview... not that easy to find a good documentation especially to change the template...  I 'll try to present what I did to look exactly like what I asked above..